# Apache plugin not working for Let's Encrypt

Tags: apache, centos7, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to secure my CentOS 7 VPS with Let's Encrypt. I've followed the guidelines in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7 . I've set up virtual hosts, installed server dependencies and the Let's Encrypt client. But when I try to set up the SSL certificate with:

```
    ./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d example.com -d mail.example.com
```

I get the error:

```
    The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
    The error was: NoInstallationError()
```

The Apache Plugin for Let's Encrypt is not working, but how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Same error on CentOS 7 and Apache 2.4. Checked through my configuration, had a couple of IfModule lines that were not closed with /IfModule. Apache is OK with them, but apparently certbot parser isn't. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score -1):

appretnly they are a bug in the letsencrypt-auto script, you can use this command to do the job.

```
sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer apache -d <yourdomain> --pre-hook "systemctl stop apache2" --post-hook "systemctl start apache2"
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer is not working. In my cases i checked apache config file and found the following line at the end of it `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` It was not making sense. On removing it the renewal went on without a problem